# Freetype dependencies on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, dependencies, freetype

I'm trying to move a project from Windows over to Linux for the first time and I'm having a little trouble including freetype (ft2build.h).

Previously the pre-compiled binaries would be used, now I am using cmake to create the freetype library and see there are a few options:
[image]

I searched around and found zlib and libPNG, but I'm not sure how necessary is it to have these dependencies. What are the benefits of these dependencies and would freetype still be able to load .ttf and .otf files without them?